# Load .xlsx into pandas as string

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am loading an xlsx file into pandas. One of the rows contains numbers, but some have a preceeding 0, such as 0734. Pandas converts them automatically into integers and the preceeding 0 is lost. How can I force pandas to import the whole xlsx file as strings?

The following doesn't work:

```
lookup = xls_file.parse('lookup',dtype=str)
```

Comment: You can't tell pandas to force the `dtype` because it uses external modules to load xls, the dtype will be sniffed from the excel sheet that defines them, you can't override this. You'll have to change the format/type of the cells in excel first

Comment: I've done that in putting '0845 to some numbers so that the 0 remains. But pandas still removes it.

Comment: Are you sure the type is string though and this is not just a display format in excel?

Comment: Could be. How can I change the type to string in excel?

Comment: In format cells... change to 'Text' under 'Number' tab in excel 2010

Comment: Pandas still converts it into int

Comment: Does the same thing happen with [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel)?

Comment: Yes, the same problem

Comment: What's your pandas, numpy version?

Comment: python 2.7.11,  pandas '0.17.1', numpy '1.9.2'

Comment: OK can you post this as an issue on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) with sample data and code, this may have nothing to do with pandas though I suspect

Comment: thanks, submitted issue here:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12186